# Uploading larger files with User-Agent python-requests/2.2.1 results in RemoteDisconnected

Tags: python-requests, artifactory

Using the python library requests and uploading larger files I will get the error `RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')`.

However it will work if I change the default User-Agent of the library to something like "Mozilla/5.0".

Does anybody know the reason for this behaviour ?

Edit: Only happens with Property `X-Explode-Archive: true`

Comment: Is this relevant to Artifactory? Are you deploying to Artifactory??

Comment: Yes, I am uploading these files to Artifactory

Answer (score 0):

Are there any specific pattern of timeout that you could highlight in this case?
For example: It times out after 60 seconds every time (of that sort)?
I would suggest to check the logs from all the medium configured with the Artifactory instance. Like, Reverse-proxy & the embedded-tomcat too. As the issue is specific to large-sized files, correlate the timeout pattern with the timeouts configured from all the entities which would give us a hint towards this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the logs of the server. Uploading larger files works if I modify the Request User Agent in the REST request. I guess timeouts are configured independently from the user agent.